# Temporarily lock MYSQL table while querying?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I'm very new to working with database. I'm currently using Google Cloud SQL and accessing the database via PHP PDO.

I managed to find a website (http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) that had some example code:

```
<?php
try {
    $db->beginTransaction(); //<---- 1

    $db->exec("SOME QUERY"); //<---- 2

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SOME OTHER QUERY?");
    $stmt->execute(array($value));

    $stmt = $db->prepare("YET ANOTHER QUERY??");
    $stmt->execute(array($value2, $value3));

    $db->commit(); //<---- 3
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    //Something went wrong rollback!
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

According to the above code, if I did '$db->beginTransaction();', would that commence locking the table? Then '$db->exec("SOME QUERY");' would be as normal. And finally, '$db->commit();' would save everything above and unlock the table?

If everything were to run correctly, then should I assume that as line 2 is running, no other call to the table can be finished (they'll be queued) and other calls can only begin once line 3 here is called? I just want to know if my understanding of this process (as well as how the code is written) is accurate.

Comment: Yes, a transaction will stop any changes being made to the tables in the exec statement. You can get the full details (there is a lot more to it than just this) [at the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html) on transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you are using try/catch, you want to make sure PDO's error mode is exceptions:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php, by default it is silent.

Then, yes, when a query fails, PDO should issue an exception which will stop the execution of the `try` section.  During the `catch`, you should issue a `rollBack()` and if everything succeeds, you should issue a `commit()`.  So how you have that looks correct to me.

After you start a transaction, nothing in that connection will be saved until you run `commit()`.  `rollBack()` ends a transaction and returns to autocommit mode without saving any changes.

From http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php:

> Turns off autocommit mode. While autocommit mode is turned off,
>   changes made to the database via the PDO object instance are not
>   committed until you end the transaction by calling PDO::commit().
>   Calling PDO::rollBack() will roll back all changes to the database and
>   return the connection to autocommit mode.